# How to retry an official race in Trackmania 2 Stadium?

Tags: trackmania-2

I'm playing Trackmania 2 Stadium (beta) and I've noticed that the first time after I retry a race after beating the gold medal time, it offers to let me do an "official" race for SP points. But after that race is complete, or if I decline to do the race, I don't know how to try for another official time.

Does that option exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may only attempt an "official race" every 5 minutes. After finishing an attempt you will see a timer appear in the bottom right of the screen. Once this reaches zero, the next time you reset you will be asked if you want to try another official race.

Comment: Note - if you decline the initial offer you must wait one minute before you can change your mind. Why? Because.